# How to build a mongo-based image with a database

Tags: bash, mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I want to build a mongobased image with a database,while I can only build the image with data and then create database in container at present,I wonder if is possible to build the image that when anybody run it can get a container with the database.

my docker-build/ :

```
./dockerfile
./doc_info_product.json
./word_sim.json
./importjson.sh
```

importjson.sh

```
#!/bin/sh^M
mongoimport --db mydb --collection doc_info_product --type json --file /data/db/doc_info_product.json --jsonArray
mongoimport --db mydb --collection word_sim --type json --file /data/db/word_sim.json --jsonArray
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
COPY doc_info_product.json /data/db/doc_info_product.json 
COPY word_sim.json /data/db/word_sim.json
RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
EXPOSE 27017
VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]
CMD [ "mongod", "--smallfiles"]
```

build image:

```
docker build --rm -f dockerfile -t mymongo:1.0 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.27MB
Step 1/8 : FROM mongo
 ---> 0f57644645eb
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p /data/db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d5ef408cf76
Step 3/8 : COPY doc_info_product.json /data/db/doc_info_product.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c79927bf287
Step 4/8 : COPY word_sim.json /data/db/word_sim.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6daeb8789102
Step 5/8 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73ab4b186ef5
Step 6/8 : EXPOSE 27017
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 66787b323bbf
Step 7/8 : VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8daefe9a984
Step 8/8 : CMD [ "mongod", "--smallfiles"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 64de133825db
Successfully built 64de133825db
Successfully tagged mymongo:1.0
```

run image:

```
docker run mymongo:1.0

[initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=d935783199ad
[initandlisten] db version v3.6.2
[initandlisten] git version: 489d177dbd0f0420a8ca04d39fd78d0a2c539420
[initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
[initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
[initandlisten] modules: none
[initandlisten] build environment:
[initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
[initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
[initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
[initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true }, storage: { mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
[initandlisten]
[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
[initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
[initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=478M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
[initandlisten] Detected configuration for non-active storage engine mmapv1 when current storage engine is wiredTiger
[initandlisten]
[initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
[initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
[initandlisten]
[initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 7b49fe9e-5847-4fe1-9b34-2fca27ab4bab
[initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.6
[initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 8f254aea-76ce-4694-a55a-8e96b269a9be
[initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
[initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

create a database in contanier:

```
docker ps
d935783199ad        mymongo:1.0       ...

docker exec d935783199ad -it bash
root@d935783199ad:/# mongoimport --db mydb --collection doc_info_product --type json --file /data/db/doc_info_product.json --jsonArray
2018-02-02T03:42:29.581+0000    connected to: localhost
2018-02-02T03:42:30.166+0000    imported 1000 documents
root@d935783199ad:/# mongoimport --db mydb --collection word_sim --type json --file /data/db/word_sim.json --jsonArray
2018-02-02T03:42:45.716+0000    connected to: localhost
2018-02-02T03:42:45.787+0000    imported 1000 documents
```

check mydb:

```
root@d935783199ad:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.2
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
        http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
        http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings:
2018-02-02T03:38:57.027+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2018-02-02T03:38:57.027+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2018-02-02T03:38:57.027+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2018-02-02T03:38:57.144+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-02T03:38:57.144+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-02-02T03:38:57.144+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-02-02T03:38:57.144+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2018-02-02T03:42:50.549+0000 E -        [main] Error loading history file: FileOpenFailed: Unable to fopen() file /root/.dbshell: No such file or directory
> show dbs
admin  0.000GB
local  0.000GB
mydb   0.005GB
> use mydb
switched to db mydb
> show collections
doc_info_product
word_sim
```

I want to get `mydb.doc_info_product`and `mydb.word_sim` just via building image and then run it,so I tried:

change `dockerfile` to

```
FROM mongo
RUN mkdir -p /data/db
COPY doc_info_product.json /data/db/doc_info_product.json 
COPY word_sim.json /data/db/word_sim.json
RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
COPY importjson.sh /data/db/importjson.sh
RUN chmod +x /data/db/importjson.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/data/db/importjson.sh"]
EXPOSE 27017
VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]
CMD [ "mongod", "--smallfiles"]
```

then build:

```
docker build --rm -f dockerfile -t mymongo:2.0 .

Sending build context to Docker daemon  13.27MB
Step 1/11 : FROM mongo
 ---> 0f57644645eb
Step 2/11 : RUN mkdir -p /data/db
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d5ef408cf76
Step 3/11 : COPY doc_info_product.json /data/db/doc_info_product.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9c79927bf287
Step 4/11 : COPY word_sim.json /data/db/word_sim.json
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6daeb8789102
Step 5/11 : RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db --smallfiles
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 73ab4b186ef5
Step 6/11 : COPY importjson.sh /data/db/importjson.sh
 ---> 072a2de84dd9
Step 7/11 : RUN chmod +x /data/db/importjson.sh
 ---> Running in 4779f52a9a24
Removing intermediate container 4779f52a9a24
 ---> f262f194508a
Step 8/11 : ENTRYPOINT ["/data/db/importjson.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7624286181ac
Removing intermediate container 7624286181ac
 ---> a909f0886298
Step 9/11 : EXPOSE 27017
 ---> Running in ad28534d97fd
Removing intermediate container ad28534d97fd
 ---> 2f49377f40fd
Step 10/11 : VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]
 ---> Running in 429d04e2b24e
Removing intermediate container 429d04e2b24e
 ---> ed081dc3bf4e
Step 11/11 : CMD [ "mongod", "--smallfiles"]
 ---> Running in 1c6f53af7bbd
Removing intermediate container 1c6f53af7bbd
 ---> 6aa20c93a7f4
Successfully built 6aa20c93a7f4
Successfully tagged mymongo:2.0
```

then run:

```
docker run mymongo:2.0

standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

my docker info:

```
Containers: 79
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 74
Images: 95
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: pb9z7cctp5bx1xzuj125shh69
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: qaip1vuuq1bno94xn8tz6ipql
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
 Autolock Managers: false
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 192.168.65.3
 Manager Addresses:
  192.168.65.3:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.934GiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d327211
ID: S3WK:QDKK:XGGV:VQJY:Z3XC:5YQD:QQSF:3FSM:WJ3Z:34GU:35FZ:DKMH
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 81
 Goroutines: 208
 System Time: 2018-02-02T04:20:08.6685331Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I donnot know whether it is possible to build a image with a databse that anyone else can use it just pull and run the image.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks like a problem in your Dockerfile or Bash script with some invalid paths. Post your script too, to help to see the actual problem. Regardless, here's a general way to achieve what you want:

Just add a bash script to Dockerfile to do your job. Then you can create a database and also add data to it using the bash script.

Here's sample code to create user and database:

```
mongo admin << EOF
use admin;
db.createUser({
    user: 'useradmin',
    pwd: '${PASS}',
    roles:[{
        role:'userAdminAnyDatabase',
        db:'admin'
    }]
});
exit
EOF

mongo admin -u useradmin -p ${PASS} << EOF
use DbName;
db.createUser({
    user: ${USER},
    pwd: ${PASS},
    roles:[{
        role:'readWrite',
        db:${DATABASE}
    }]
});
exit
EOF
```

Here's a sample code to add data:

```
mongo -u yourUser -p yourPass DbName << EOF
 ...Your_MongoDB_Commands_Here
EOF
```

If this isn't clear enough, I did something similar to one of my older projects (the scripts are based off another source I do not remember, but should help regardless). Here's the link to relevant files: [Github](https://github.com/Jaskaranbir/InstaPost/tree/master/MongoDB).

Comment: Your codes here seem to generate db first and update data when it is running,  and it would be useful to initial dbs with certifications,but here I have certain database with huge data, I surely cant insert them one by one after start the service with `mongo`. Im new to docker and hoping how to use `mongoimport` here if it can.